# "state channel" v.s "micro-payment channel" : are they the same?

Tags: blockchain, lightning-network, micropaymentchannels, micropayments, off-chain

We use "`micro-payment channels`" such as "[Bitcoin Lightning Network](https://dci.mit.edu/lightning-network/)" or "[Duplex Micro-Payment Channels](https://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/716b955c130e6c703fac336ea17b1670/duplex-micropayment-channels.pdf)" for saving transaction fee, accelerating payments, supporting better micro-payment and scaling blockchain.

Is there any difference between "`state channel`" v.s "`micro-payment channe`l"? and if so, what are **differences**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Payment channels are a specific form of state channels used for forwarding payments (as in the Lightning network). State channels are a more abstract idea: In theory you could use the ideas of cryptographically securing a state between two or more participants (the balance in payment channels) backed by a blockchain for something else than payments (like games). But, just as with blockchains, it is highly doubtful if this actually makes sense economically for anything else than money itself.